# Почему PDO query возвращает false?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Почему var_dump($result) возвращает false? Данные вроде верно, несколько раз проверил.

```php
$dsn = "mysql:host = 127.0.0.1;dbname = bd_parking;charset=utf8";
$username = 'root';
$passwd = '1234';
$option = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]; 

try{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `client`";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);

    var_dump($result);

}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: *PDO::query() возвращает объект PDOStatement или **FALSE, если запрос выполнить не удалось.*** Добавьте вывод ошибок...

Comment: `$option` то вы  на кой завели?

Comment: оуч щас исправлю

Comment: Пишет SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected ,а если через  mysqli_query всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

Причина была здесь `$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=bd_parking;charset=utf8";`
Надо убрать пробелы.